# Aliasing a singleton object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

So I don't really have a practical purpose for this, but as I was switching between JavaScript and Ruby on my client side and server side code a mixed up my nil and null and thought "why not alias null to nil and vice versa" then just forget about it (not something I would really put in to the project), but would this even be possible?

So I tried both alias and alias_method on nil and tried tying back to NilClass to no avail.  Is there away to alias a singleton object like `nil` in Ruby?

Comment: @sawa: I think he means that he uses `nil` in JS where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sawa, Yes as Sergio says.  In JavaScript I might reference `nil` when it should be `null`; in Ruby I might reference `null` where it should be `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Write a "Null" Method

You can't alias nil because it's a singleton instance of NilClass, not a method. You also can't duplicate it because it's a singleton. However, you can certainly have a custom method that *returns* nil, which pretty much gives you the results you're expecting for most use cases.

```
def null; nil; end

null.class
#=> NilClass

null == nil
#=> true

null === nil
#=> true

null.is_a? NilClass
#=> true

null.instance_of? NilClass
#=> true
```